# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The database name '****.amazonaws.com' (85 characters) is longer than PostgreSQL's limit of 63 characters

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to migrate my Django model to the AWS Lightsail database, but I am getting below error. My database is on AWS Lightsail. it is PostgreSQL. I am deploying my project on AWS so I have set up almost everything except model migration.

**AMAZON DATABASE AVAILABLE CONNECTION OPTIONS:**

```
    Endpoint->  ************.ap-******-1.***.amazonaws.com,
    Port->    5444,
    User name->  db,
    Password->  Something
```

**MY SETTINGS.PY FILE DATABASE CONNECTION OPTIONS:**

```
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': '****Endpoint*****',
            'USER': 'db',
            'PASSWORD': 'Something',
            'HOST': '5444'
        }
    }
```

**Terminal Error:**

````
> `2, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", lin
e 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", lin
e 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in 
inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line
 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line
 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in 
inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line
 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in 
inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line
 196, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/home/bitnami/portfolio/ManojJha-portfolio/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py"
, line 165, in get_connection_params
    self.ops.max_name_length(),
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The database name '*****************Database End-point*****************.***.amazonaws.com' (85 characters) is longer than PostgreSQL's limit of 63 characters. Supply a shorter NAME in settings.DATABASES.```
````

So is there any way to **shorten** the **endpoint** name or there is any other solution to handle this error. Please guide me to set up this.

Thanks,
-Manoj Jha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"HOST" should be the hostname, not the port!
"NAME" is the name of the database.

An example from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#s-id13):

```py
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
'NAME': 'xe',
'USER': 'a_user',
'PASSWORD': 'a_password',
'HOST': 'dbprod01ned.mycompany.com',
'PORT': '1540',
```

Comment: Following details are available for database conection. Not sure which is Host in this as They have given only endpoint.  Endpoint->  ************.ap-******-1.***.amazonaws.com,
    Port->    5444,
    User name->  db,
    Password->  Something

Comment: @ManojJha `HOST` is the endpoint, `PORT` is the port, `USER` is the username, `NAME` is the db and `PASSWORD` is your password

Comment: Thanks, @Rafael finally it works. I had to connect AWS DB to my Local DB to find DB name so after that now it is working. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Most appreciated